# Watermelon in a water bucket in a centrifuge

Tags: pressure

We had a discussion about throwing a water melon using the [SpinLaunch satellite launcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpinLaunch).

One of the first points was that the centrifugal force would squash the water melon before it could be launched.

So what would happen if you put the water melon (which has a slightly lower density than water) in a water container into the centrifuge of the SpinLaunch?

Would it make a difference whether the container was sealed airtight or if air could enter the container?

Comment: Will density be a deciding factor? what about shell strength?

Comment: Why would the presence of water or air protect the water melon if the rotational speed is sufficiently high ?

Comment: @ajn one think I can think of (although it's a conjecture) is that if the pressure is high enough the hydrostatic stress could arrest the "failure" of the water melon.(it might be completely nonsense though).

Comment: The idea behind the water was that, kinda how a helium balloon floats backwards in a car that slows down, the water that is just heavyer than the melon would cancel the outward force. (Which again might be nonsense, but that was the argument being brought forward)

Comment: From the melon's point of view, for going at V speed with a radius r, something or the other, needs to apply a force of $mv^2/r$. It can be wall of the container or the water in the container. Only difference would be that the water would probably apply the force which is equally distributed over the melon's surface while the container would apply that same force over the contact area which could be much smaller than the other case.

Comment: @AJN That makes a lot of sense. So the water container could possibly help by distributing the force to a bigger part of the melon, but it will not negate the pressure in any way. Is that correct?